# How do I assign an IP address to an LXC container?

Tags: networking, network-bridge, lxc

I'm trying to start lxc containers with their own public ip address on the network. This is what I've tried so far:

#### On the host

The host machine has an IP address of 192.168.255.254. I added a bridge, br0, in the same subnet:

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
    address 192.168.255.254
    netmask 255.255.0.0
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
    address 192.168.255.1
    netmask 255.255.0.0
```

I've also enabled ip forwarding (`net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1` in `/etc/sysctl.d/20-lxc.conf` as per [this guide](http://www.greenhills.co.uk/2011/06/10/lxc.html))

In `/var/lib/lxc/$NAME/config`:

```
lxc.network.type=veth
lxc.network.link=br0
lxc.network.name=eth1
```

#### On the container

In `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
    address 192.168.255.99
    netmask 255.255.0.0
```

When I try to start the container, it can't get an IP address:

```
cloud-init-container: emitted ifup for eth1
cloud-init start-local running: Thu, 11 Apr 2013 07:27:54 +0000. up 1592.73 seconds
no instance data found in start-local
cloud-init-nonet waiting 120 seconds for a network device.
cloud-init-nonet gave up waiting for a network device.
ci-info: lo    : 1 127.0.0.1       255.0.0.0       .
ci-info: eth1  : 1 .               .               00:16:3e:cf:20:b5
route_info failed
```

This is the output of `route`:

```
default         10.0.2.2        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
default         10.0.2.2        0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
10.0.2.0        *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
10.0.3.0        *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 lxcbr0
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth1
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See if [this](http://lxc.sourceforge.net/index.php/about/kernel-namespaces/network/configuration/) can help you.

Comment: Turns out recent releases of lxc already do everything you need, which I didn't notice because there was another networking problem.